# Аналог display:none при создании андроид приложения?

Tags: activity, android

Аналог display:none при создании андроид приложения?

Comment: вы кажется забыли написать тело вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textView.setViewsibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: View.GONE больше по смыслу подходит.